# How do I write a function that satisfies this test?

Tags: python, function, decorator

I need to write a function that satisfies this test in pytest:

```
def test_return_logger(capsys):
@return_logger
def myfunc(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

val = myfunc(4, 5, 6)
out, err = capsys.readouterr()

assert val == 15
assert "Function returned: 15" in out
```

Here is what I currently have and it is not working:

```
def return_logger(f):
def newfunc(s):
    original_return_value = f(s)
    return f"Function returned: {original_return_value}"
return newfunc
```

Im honestly completely lost!

Comment: capsys is a builtin pytest fixture that can be passed into any test to capture stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Your test wants the function to *return* the value, and *print* the string that you were returning.

The `newfunc(*args)` also solves passing in multiple arguments - they are automatically unpacked when calling the second function.

You probably want this:

```py
def return_logger(f):
    def newfunc(*args):
        original_return_value = f(*args)
        print(f"Function returned: {original_return_value}", sys.stderr)
        return original_return_value
    return newfunc
```

Now, when you call the decorated function, it will print `Function returned: 15` to stderr and return `original_return_value`.